# USB ports charge but do not recognize anything I plug in / Windows 7 64

Tags: windows-7, usb

So I've been having this issue for some time. I have 1 port that recognizes only my keyboard and mouse (Logitech). The other ports charge items but does not recognize them. I have done the following:
Flashed the Bios (Acer Predator G3610)
Used both USBDeview and USBOblivion
Reinstalled the chipset software
unplugged devices and restarted the computer
unplugged the USB ports from the motherboard
Everything that I could find online to do I have tried and it's making me a little crazy. 
It's running Windows 7 x64. 
Crazy part is when I plug in a wired keyboard to the one port that works, the keyboard works. If I plug in anything else (ie printer, iphone, tablet, thumb drive) it doesn't recognize it. Any ideas on how to fix this would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[USBDevView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) can show you if there was an unusual entry in the list of all USB devices ever connected. This list can also be [accessed from the Registry](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/authentication_and_encryption/Extracting-USB-Artifacts-from-Windows-7.html). You might have an invalid item on the list causing the issue. Back up the Registry before removing an entry, though.